# Redux-form not formatting post data and [object Object] issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have two problems that are a result of each other. I populate two fields with `initialValue` data, I can then push another field to the array. The issue came about when I tried to amend the `initialValue` structure from:

```
  initialValues: {
    rockSingers: [ "Axl Rose", "Brian Johnson"]
  }
```

to:

```
  initialValues: {
    rockSingers: [{ singer: "Axl Rose" }, { singer: "Brian Johnson" }]
  }
```

The first problem is that the field now returns `[object Object]`. Upon submitting the form the correct `json` format is displayed until I come on to my 2nd issue... when adding a new value that does not format the same as the `initialValue` data - e.g.

```
{
  "rockSingers": [
    {
      "singer": "Axl Rose"
    },
    {
      "singer": "Brian Johnson"
    },
    "Tom Rudge"
  ]
}
```

Here is the codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/8kzw0pw408

Comment: if you are not using any nested FieldArray , then you could  specifies initial value in array format   `initialValues: {
    rockSingers: [ "Axl Rose" , "Brian Johnson" ]
  }` rest of things will be works as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `renderRockSingers` so that you are grabbing the object, not a string.

```js
const renderRockSingers = ({ fields }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>Rock Singers:</h3>
    {fields.map((rockSinger) => (
      <div>
        <Field name={`${rockSinger}.singer`} key="index" component="input" />
      </div>
    ))}
    <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>
      Add more
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

More on the `FieldArray` component here: [fieldarrays](https://redux-form.com/7.0.2/examples/fieldarrays/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const renderRockSingers = ({ fields }) => (
      <div>
        <h3>Rock Singers:</h3>
        {fields.map((rockSinger, index) => (
          <div>
            <Field
              name={rockSinger}
              format={value => value.singer}
              parse={value => ({ singer: value })}
              key={index}
              component="input"
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({ singer: '' })}>
          Add more
        </button>
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Field
  name={rockSinger}
  key={index}
  component="input"
  format={(value, name) => (value !== undefined ? value.singer : "")}
  normalize={value => ({ singer: value })}
/>
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/7m1p9600y0

Comment: This is a good answer, I used this for my scenario where I had other things going on. Thanks